# How can I delete an account in parity if I don't know the password?

Tags: parity

Parity is asking for a password to delete an account, which I cannot give it. How do I get rid of the account?

Answer (score 2):

***This is very bad advice and you may lose ether if you're not sure of what you're doing***, but I would:

1. Find the keystore
2. Make a backup of the keystore
3. Find the JSON file for the account you want to remove
4. Move that file to a different location on your hard drive
5. Restart your browser

The account should disappear from Parity. I won't tell you where the keystore is because it's in different places on different operating systems.

Make sure to backup everything. Make sure to ***copy*** not delete the account file. Make sure you understand that you will lose ether if you delete the wrong file.